# The executable only work when open by Terminal C Allegro

Tags: c, image, macos, terminal, allegro

I have a really weird issue, I'm working on an Allegro game, I compile on terminal and code on XCode Code Viewer(it's like an text editor), everything were going good, but when I load a image and run the executable by click it give me the error "Can't load image", the interesting fact is that when I open the executable by terminal (./executablename) it works exactly as it shoud! I really don't understand why, someone told me that error might be something about permissions, but I don't understand much about mac...  and don't know hot to solve it.

here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

//puxa a biblioteca allegro
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_primitives.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_image.h>

//fixo de tamanho de tela
#define LAR 1280
#define ALT 720

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    //inicialização da janela
    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *janela = NULL;

    ALLEGRO_BITMAP *imagem = NULL;

    //inicia allegro, caso erro da a msg
    if(!al_init()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to initialize allegro!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    al_get_standard_path(ALLEGRO_RESOURCES_PATH);

    //cria a janela
    janela = al_create_display(LAR, ALT);
    if(!janela) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to create display!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    //inicia primitivos
    //al_init_primitives_addon();

    //inicia a extenção de imagens
    if(!al_init_image_addon()){
        fprintf(stderr, "Falha ao carregar image addon");
    }

    //carrega imagem
    imagem = al_load_bitmap("imagem.jpg");
    if (!imagem){
        fprintf(stderr, "Falha ao carregar imagem!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    //preenche a tela com alguma cor
    al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0,0,0));

    //desenha imagem
    al_draw_bitmap(imagem, LAR/2 - (al_get_bitmap_width(imagem)/2),
                   ALT/2 - (al_get_bitmap_height(imagem)/2), 0);

    //atualiza a tela
    al_flip_display();

    //pausa a execução
    al_rest(10.0);

    //destroi imagem
    al_destroy_bitmap(imagem);

    //destroi variavel janela
    al_destroy_display(janela);

    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with XCode or macs neither, however... that looks like a pretty common issue I had with Visual Studio in the past:

When you are executing a program from the debugger or within the IDE's environment, the IDE starts the program from a diferent directory than the one the binary is located (For example, where the project/solution file resides). So that when you try to locate the image it fails because it is no in the folder.

Try moving the image around near the project file or inside other directories in your workspace for that application until it loads, or modify environment variables in the code editor so that the binary's startup folder is the one where you store the image.